# How to send multiple elements as ajax response in CakePHP 2.0.6

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, element

In my view I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.go_button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Controller/find_by_location",
                data: "city=New%York",
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#coupons_results').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my controller:

```
public function find_by_location(){
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->TblLocalDeal->recursive = 3;
        $city = "New york";   //just for test
        $zipcode = "";        //testing
        $conditions = array(...);
        $result = $this->paginate('Table', $conditions);
        $this->layout = null;
        foreach($results as $result):
            $this->set('var', $result['index']);
            $this->render('/elements/local_coupon');
        endforeach;
    }
```

This is only sending the html for the first element. How can I send all the html from the other elements rendered inside the foreach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Cake 2.x.

`$this->render()` returns a response object and doesn't output a response until you tell it. To get the response, try something like this in your loop:

```
$out = '';
foreach($results as $result):
   $this->set('var', $result['index']);
   $response = $this->render('/elements/local_coupon');
   $out .= $response->body();
endforeach;
echo $out;
```

This will gather all of the rendered content and echo it out to your ajax response.

Note: this doesn't send headers so you should probably do that manually. I suggest instead of using this approach you create a view for `find_by_location()` and echo the elements there, and let Cake handle sending headers and content.